# Tensorflow Callbacks in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am currently learning `TensorFlow` and understand the nice convenience that callbacks add, being able to stop your epochs once a desired level of accuracy in obtained.  What I don't understand is the object `tf.keras.callbacks.Callback` passed into the class callback on this code I am studying.  I am normally just used to a class with the word *object* in it or nothing at all.
When I type `tf.keras.callbacks.Callback` it returns `type`.  Would anyone be able to explain why `tf.keras.callbacks.Callback` is passed into this callback class?

```
class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    if(logs.get('accuracy')>0.95):
      print("\nReached 60% accuracy so cancelling training!")
      self.model.stop_training = True
```

Comment: You might want to look up the concept of "inheritance".

Comment: As mentioned @Lescurel its concept of "inheritance". Method `tf.keras.callbacks.Callback` is called inside class callback because Callbacks can be passed to keras methods such as fit, evaluate, and predict in order to hook into the various stages of the model training and inference lifecycle. Tensorflow provides us to write custom callback. please refer [Tensorflow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback). Thanks!